# Input Value set with javascript retrieve in codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

So I have a repeater that creates `<li>` elements. This is the codebehind for the `OnItemDataBound`

```
var categoryList = (ProductCategoryObject) e.Item.DataItem;
            var category = ((HtmlAnchor) e.Item.FindControl("category"));
            category.HRef = "javascript:void(0);";
            category.InnerText = categoryList.Name;
            category.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:$('#ProductCategory').val('" + categoryList.Id + "');$('button.product-categories span').text('" + categoryList.Name + "');");
```

This sets the value of an input of type hidden and now my question is how do I get that value on button click? It appears to disappear on postback and I've tried `Request["ProductCategory"]` and `Request.Form["ProductCategory"]`

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-30">
    <div id="divCategories" runat="server" class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn blue dropdown-toggle  product-categories" data-toggle ="dropdown">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCategory">All Categories</asp:Label> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
        </button>
        <ul runat="server" ID="ulCategory" class="dropdown-menu">
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptCategories" OnItemDataBound="CategoriesOnItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <a runat="server" id="category"></a>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
        <input id="ProductCategory" type="hidden" />
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFilter" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="BaseValidationGroup" CssClass="btn green" OnClick="SearchBtnOnClick"> Search <i class="icon-search"></i> </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you need to add runat="server" on that bad boy?

Comment: @AdamHeeg reading other posts they said otherwise, I tried with that and it still didn't work...

Comment: Request.Form["ProductCategory"] is the way to get the value... so you need to check if the value is changed before the submit... you can debbug in browser (F12) or use an alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I had to change my the markup for my input control from

```
<input id="ProductCategory" type="hidden" />
```

to

```
<input id="ProductCategory" name="ProductCategory" type="hidden" />
```

So, essentially, I was missing the `name` tag which is needed for `Request.Form["ProductCategory"]` to work.